# FacebookSDKException: Session not active, could not store state

Tags: facebook-php-sdk

I don't understand why I'm getting this exceptions:

```
Session not active, could not store state.
```

The code is:

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('foo', 'baz');

$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('bar');
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl();

?>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You need to start a session using `session_start()` for the Facebook SDK to work correctly. Please add this to your code to fix the issue.

Example:

```
<?php

session_start();

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;

...
```

Comment: If you don't want to use the default $_SESSION to store the state, you can [extend the storeState class using this linked example](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4/issues/39#issuecomment-42363729). The example uses Laravel sessions but you can use whatever you want inside your extension.

Comment: Yupp That worked for me, Thank You So much @Niraj Shah. I forgot to use redirectloginhelper.

Comment: You've got to be kidding me... All this time I was looking into Facebook session...