# Symfony2 and PHP SDK 4.0 session issue while login

Tags: php, facebook, symfony, session, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am trying to integrate [Facebook PHP-SDK 4](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4) and Symfony2

I installed Facebook SDK using composer and using some basic code from Facebook developer documentation

**Generate Facebook Login Url**

```
public function indexAction(Request $request) {
        //Generate
        FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('appId', 'secret');
        $redirectUrl = $this->generateUrl('auth_facebookredirect');
        $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper($redirectUrl);
        $helper->disableSessionStatusCheck();
        $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl();
        return $this->render('UserBundle:FB:index.html.twig', array('loginUrl'=>$loginUrl));
    }
```

**Callback or Facebook Redirect after login success**

```
public function successAction(Request $request) {
        FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('appId', 'secret');

        $redirectUrl = $this->generateUrl('auth_facebookredirect');
        $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper();
        //$session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();

        try {
            $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();

        } catch (FacebookRequestException $ex) {
            echo " When Facebook returns an error";
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {            
            echo " When validation fails or other local issues";
        }
        if ($session) {
            $me = (new FacebookRequest(
                    $session, 'GET', '/me'
                    ))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());
            var_dump($me);
        }
        return $this->render('UserBundle:FB:success.html.twig', array());
    }
```

First I got error

`FacebookSDKException: Session not active, could not store state.`

I came across [this link](http://www.ophidia.net/insane/symfony2-und-die-facebook-php-sdk-4/?lang=en) and it says there is issue with session and used

`$helper->disableSessionStatusCheck();`

because of this login worked, but when I got redirected to Facebook callback URL / Redirect URL after FB login I got Exception that

`DefaultApplication is not set`

so I added `FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('appId', 'secret');` at `successAction`

still I get error after login at section below, I can't get session here.

```
try {
            $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();

        } catch (FacebookRequestException $ex) {
            echo " When Facebook returns an error";
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {            
            echo " When validation fails or other local issues"; 
        }
```

**I get error here** `catch (\Exception $ex) {

                echo " When validation fails or other local issues"; 
            }`

`$session =   helper->getSessionFromRedirect();`

what is causing error here, my Facebook login Credentials are correct.

I am unable to figure out this error.

Comment: What does $ex->getMessage() says?

Comment: @Ugur "Session not active, could not load state."  this is the error. I think the way Symfony2 handle sessions and for Facebook its different

Comment: have you tried those answers?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/23524716/3399234
http://stackoverflow.com/a/24194208/3399234

Comment: I did that and after that there is some session error, It was due to some session handling issue. I needed to check if there is already facebook session already present or not. thanks @Ugur

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it this way.

```
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper(
                $this->generateUrl('app_home',[],true),//generates absolute ur;
                $this->container->getParameter('facebook_sdk.app_id'), //api id
                $this->container->getParameter('facebook_sdk.app_secret')//app secret
            );
```